# Monotouch - UIActionSheet not displaying correctly on iPad

Tags: ipad, mono, xamarin.ios, uiactionsheet

I have a UIActionSheet that works just fine on the iPhone simulator. It is presented when the user touches a UIButton.

Using the iPad, I believe UIActionSheets are wrapped into a UIPopupController.

When I call the same code using the iPad simulator, I get a thin "line" displayed, which looks like a UIPopupController (you can see the small arrow that usually points to a control). None of the content can be seen.

What is the correct way to use a UIActionSheet using the iPad with MonoTouch? Here is a bit of sample code I have been testing with - creating the UIActionSheet:

```
var actionSheet = new UIActionSheet () { Style = UIActionSheetStyle.BlackTranslucent };
        actionSheet.Frame = actionSheetFrame;
        actionSheet.Clicked += (s, e) => { Console.WriteLine ("Clicked on item {0}", e.ButtonIndex); };
actionSheet.AddSubview (doneButton);
```

Then, I am showing the actionsheet by calling the following from a button:

```
btnSay.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
            actionSheet.ShowFrom(tmpBtn.Frame, tmpView, false);
        };
```

I get something like the attached screenshot when using the iPad simulator.

[image: iPad UIActionSheet example]

For reference, here is what the UIActionSheet looks like when using the iPhone simulator.

[image: iPhone UIActionSheet example]

Note: The project is a universal single-view MonoTouch c# project.

Any pointers or help would be much appreciated!

Comment: When btnSay is touched, what is tmpBtn.Frame? What about tmpView?  I would guess you want to be showing the actionSheet from btnSay.Frame inside of btnSay.Superview.

Comment: Hi Jacob, tmpBtn.Frame is the frame / rectangle of a button on the main View. tmpView is essentially just "View" i.e. the main view that is currently showing. I'll give what you say a try - thanks!

Comment: Hi Jacob, sorry I see what you are saying now - was a little rushed earlier. Yes, as it stands I am already trying to show the actionSheet like this - using 3 x parameters - the frame of the button btnSay.Frame, the superview of the button, and true/false for animated or not. Like this, I am getting the issue as depicted in my screenshot above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced this same problem with a recent app I released to the app store.

When you show a `UIActionSheet` on iPad, iOS wraps the `UIActionSheet` in a `UIPopoverView`.

I used the following code to detect whether this is an iPad, and if it is, adjust the frame of the popover view:

```
const int CHROMEWIDTHLEFT = 9;
const int CHROMEWIDTHRIGHT = 8;
const int MARGIN = 50;

UIActionSheet _actionSheet;

...

if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad) {
    var popover = _actionSheet.Superview.Superview;
    if (popover != null)
    {
        var x = _actionSheet.Frame.X + MARGIN;
        var y = (UIScreen.MainScreen.ApplicationFrame.Height - _actionSheet.Frame.Height) / 2;
        var width = _actionSheet.Frame.Width - (MARGIN * 2);
        var height = _actionSheet.Frame.Height;

        popover.Frame = new RectangleF (x, y, width, height);
        _actionSheet.Frame = new RectangleF (x, y, width - (CHROMEWIDTHLEFT + CHROMEWIDTHRIGHT), height - (CHROMEWIDTHLEFT + CHROMEWIDTHRIGHT));
    }
}
```

The example is based upon the Xamarin ActionSheet Date Picker [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/recipes/Standard_Controls/ActionSheet/ActionSheet_Date_Picker)

I have put these up as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/4053306) (Normal and DatePicker)

Comment: Hi Macropus, thanks for posting your solution. I'll give this a try tomorrow and report back. My issue was actually modifying the frame itself - so this looks promising!

Comment: Hi Macropus, sorry for not coming back to you on this - I had a quick attempt, didn't have any luck, but think there was something at fault on my side - I have been caught up in business and plan to try this out again - possibly over the weekend. I'll post back here as soon as I have had a better look! (probably over the coming week). Thanks for checking back.